# Luhn Algoritm for social security numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just got some negative feedback on some code I wrote and I was not able to know exactly what was wrong with it (I tried). It is a program that verifies to see if a social security number is valid or not. The program is working fine.So I would really appreciate it if somebody could take a look and tell me if this can be optimized in some way.

Here is the code:

```
public class Logic
{
    public static bool ValidityChecker(string socialSecurityNumber)
    {
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo("C:\\Log\\log.txt"); //Checks to see if folder path exists. Otherwise creates a C:\Log\ folder.
        if (!f.Directory.Exists)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(f.DirectoryName);
        }

        if (ValidityCheckIsNotNull(socialSecurityNumber) == true && ValidityCheckIsSSN(socialSecurityNumber) == true) //If the string is not null/empty and if the Social Security Number is valid, then return true.
            return true;
        else //If the string is null/empty or the social security number is invalid. Then log the invalid data and return false.
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("C:\\Log\\log.txt", true))
            {
                w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Kandidatdata: " + socialSecurityNumber.ToString());
                w.Close();
            }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool ValidityCheckIsNotNull(string socialSecurityNumber) //If string is null or empty return false. Otherwise return true.
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(socialSecurityNumber))
            return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public static bool ValidityCheckIsSSN(string socialSecurityNumber) //Uses the algoritm (from the task documentation) to see if a Social Security number is valid or not.
    {
        int totalSSN = socialSecurityNumber.Where((e) => e >= '0' && e <= '9').Reverse().Select((e, i) => (e - 48) * (i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 2)).Sum((e) => e / 10 + e % 10);
        return totalSSN % 10 == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: for ````ValidityCheckIsNotNull(string)```` you can just write ````return string.IsNullOrEmpty(socialSecurityNumber);```` The worse thing you can say about code, 'is it works.' But you are trying to see what is wrong with the code, and that is a good start! One other item id get rid of is the multiple returns in all the functions, some of them are kinda hard to follow along with. especially if you are running a command before doing a return false. It would be much easier just to assign the bool to a variable and then return that. IMHO multiple returns can be bad.

Answer (score 2):

Some quick remarks:

- Use clear variable names: `f` doesn't tell me anything.
- Why do you call `Directory.CreateDirectory` before you do the actual validity check?
- Do you even need to call `Directory.CreateDirectory`? I'm not sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if `new StreamWriter("C:\\Log\\log.txt", true)` creates any missing directories etc.
- `"C:\\Log\\log.txt"` is used in two places, so it should be at least centralized. Assign it to a variable or perhaps even a constant.
- You wrote a whole method -- `ValidityCheckIsNotNull` -- to encapsulate `string.IsNullOrEmpty`? ***WHY?*** What do you gain from this? What's the point?
- Your lines are waaay too long. 170 characters which contain multiple LINQ methods are simply unclear. At least split it up into multiple lines.

Here is that same code, split over multiple lines:

```
socialSecurityNumber
   .Where((e) => e >= '0' && e <= '9')
   .Reverse()
   .Select((e, i) => (e - 48) * (i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 2))
   .Sum((e) => e / 10 + e % 10);
```

Already it's a lot clearer. However, you need to comment this: `.Select((e, i) => (e - 48) * (i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 2))` because I cannot figure out easily what this logic is supposed to do. Properly naming `e` and `i` would help, I guess. Or even better: move it to a properly named method of its own.

- Comments like `//If the string is not null/empty and if the Social Security Number is valid, then return true.` don't tell me anything your code doesn't tell me.
- `ValidityChecker` isn't a proper method name: ["Use verbs or verb phrases to name methods."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw.aspx)
- All of your logging logic should be in a separate method. It should not be part of `ValidityChecker`.
- `Logic` as the name of your class? Far too generic.

Answer (score 2):

From top to bottom:

`Logic` is not a good name for a class, it should convey some information about its content. I'm generally against *utility classes* like this but without more context I can't suggest anything better, at least check name to `SocialSecurityNumber` and mark it as `static` (in this moment you can create an instance of it). Note that you may want to give it some dignity and create a **new type** `SocialSecurityNumber`.

`ValidityChecker` is not a good method name because it does not convey any information about what it actually does, I'd rename it to `IsValidNumber`, calling point will be more clear: `SocialSecurityNumber.IsValidNumber(text)` and I'd drop logging, make another method to do both operations.

You hardcoded an absolute file path, move it to another place (for example configuration). Also you repeat such path more than once, save it into a local variable.

Check for directory existence can be simplified and should be moved to another method.

```
private static EnsurePathExists(string path)
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    if (!di.Exists)
        di.Create();
}
```

With this calling point:

```
EnsurePathExists(Path.GetDirectoryName(logFilePath));
```

Also note that I/O operations may fail, I suggest a retry-pattern to handle transitory issues.

`ValidityCheckIsNotNull()` should be (at least from code you posted) private and it may be simplified to:

```
public static bool ValidityCheckIsNotNull(string socialSecurityNumber)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(socialSecurityNumber);
}
```

As you can see now it's so simple that it may be simply dropped (and merged into `ValidityCheckIsSSN`, see later).

Comments are redundant, you merely repeat what you already have in code. Just drop them because you will need to maintain them but they do not add any value.

Multi-line else block without brackets is hard to read and it's also useless, if condition is satisfied you already have a `return`.

With `using` you do not need to explicitly close the stream with `w.Close()`.

`socialSecurityNumber` is already a string, no need to call `socialSecurityNumber.ToString()`.

To create a composed string (if you're using *older* C# compiler without interpolated strings) you can use `String.Format()`.

```
public static bool ValidateAndLogIfInvalid(string socialSecurityNumber)
{
    if (IsValidNumber(socialSecurityNumber))
        return true;

    LogInvalidNumber(socialSecurityNumber);

    return false;
}

public static bool IsValidNumber(string socialSecurityNumber)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialSecurityNumber))
        return false;

    // ...
}

private static bool LogInvalidNumber(string socialSecurityNumber)
{
    string logFilePath = ResolveLogFilePath();
    EnsurePathExists(Path.GetDirectoryName(logFilePath));

    File.AppendText(logFilePath, String.Format("{0} Kandidatdata: {1}, 
        DateTime.Now, socialSecurityNumber);
}
```

Note that you may want to throw `ArgumentNullException` if `socialSecurityNumber` is `null`...

SSN validation algorithm is pretty hard to understand, don't make one line for that and describe each step in source code (with a reference to documentation).

Also about comments: use XML comments if you're documenting public methods.